# Change stackexchange.com user profile picture

Tags: support, profile-page

How do I change my profile pic in my account or avatar?  I signed up under my email for the account and I can't figure out how to change it from the current profile pic/avatar.

Answer (score 3):

Four simple steps...

1. Click your 'Reputation', top right.
2. Click 'Edit Profile & Settings
3. Click 'Change picture' at the bottom of your existing avatar
4. Upload a new picture or change Identicon

   [image]

   Oops, don't forget
5. Click Save for this site or entire SE network at the bottom of the page.

   [image: Save]